# How to filter unit tests by xUnit.net trait attribute when using VS test explorer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit.net, test-explorer

Say I have integration tests with signature like:

```
[Fact]
[Trait("Category", "Integration")]
public async Task FooTest()
```

If I want to run only unit tests, in dotnet core [I can run tests selectively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=xunit):

```sh
dotnet test --filter category!=Integration
```

How can I achieve the same with Visual Studio Test Explorer?

I considered using a [.runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file), but it doesn't seem to support passing a filter parameter to it.

I do not want to use a [playlist file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file), as I will have to manually keep it in sync with any changes to unit or integration tests.

**Related issue**: [No longer able to group by trait in Test Explorer with VS 2019 Preview](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/no-longer-able-to-group-by-trait-in-test-explorer/588029)

Comment: pretty sure there's a visual trait filter up top - if not, there's def the ability to use the search filter box to express it as a query

Comment: That kind of works, but unfortunately requires several clicks every time VS is restarted. I would like to have a 1 click solution of "run unit tests".

Comment: Not a bad idea to click the feedback icon and suggest a way to persist searches somewhere (though that .runsettings overkill seems to be the thinking they have had in that space historically). Aaaand there's a thing called Rider ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't want to use a playlist, but I think that might be the best answer here.

Using the `Not` keyword for the match will exclude your filter, so the following playlist will include any xUnit test that is in the solution and is not in the "Integration" category.

```
<Playlist Version="2.0">
  <Rule Match="Not" >
      <Property Name="Trait" Value="Category [Integration]" />  
  </Rule>
</Playlist>
```

This approach also means that you shouldn't need to update the playlist when you add more tests. They'll be picked up automatically.

The format for MSTest is slightly different.

```
<Playlist Version="2.0">
    <Rule Match="Not">
        <Property Name="Trait" Value="Integration" />
    </Rule>
</Playlist>
```

You could exclude several traits by using several `Rule` elements and the `All` keyword.

```
<Playlist Version="2.0">
    <Rule Match="All">
        <Rule Match="Not" >
            <Property Name="Trait" Value="Category [Integration]" />  
        </Rule>
        <Rule Match="Not" >
            <Property Name="Trait" Value="Category [foo]" />  
        </Rule>
        <Rule Match="Not" >
            <Property Name="Trait" Value="Category [bar]" />  
        </Rule>
    </Rule>
</Playlist>
```

I found this by starting with the example provided on the [Test Explorer learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2022#create-custom-playlists) and extrapolating based on Microsoft's other, similar XML schemas. I was unable to find documentation for this feature online.